# node.js build error on cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

i'm using cygwin on windows 7 machine and installing node.js using these instruction: 
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)

i keep getting the below error when i try to build. ./configure works fine but the make command is giving me trouble. i've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find an answer. does anyone know what's wrong?

```
user-THINK ~/node-v0.4.12
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : yes
Checking for openssl                     : yes
Checking for library util                : yes
Checking for library rt                  : yes
--- libeio ---
Checking for library pthread             : yes
Checking for function pthread_create     : yes
Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes
Checking for futimes(2)                  : yes
Checking for readahead(2)                : no
Checking for fdatasync(2)                : yes
Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes
Checking for sendfile(2)                 : no
Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : no
--- libev ---
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : not found
Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : not found
Checking for header port.h               : not found
Checking for header poll.h               : yes
Checking for function poll               : yes
Checking for header ['sys/types.h', 'sys/event.h'] : not found
Checking for header sys/queue.h                    : yes
Checking for function kqueue                       : not found
Checking for header sys/select.h                   : yes
Checking for function select                       : yes
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h                  : not found
Checking for SYS_clock_gettime                     : no
Checking for library rt                            : yes
Checking for function clock_gettime                : yes
Checking for function nanosleep                    : yes
Checking for function ceil                         : yes
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++                 : yes
'configure' finished successfully (6.400s)

user ~/node-v0.4.12
$ make
Waf: Entering directory `/home/user/node-v0.4.12/build'
DEST_OS: cygwin
DEST_CPU: x64
Parallel Jobs: 1
Product type: program
[ 3/75] cc: deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c -> build/default/deps/c-ares/ares_strc                                     asecmp_1.o
/usr/bin/gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -g -O3 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -DEV_FORK_E                                     NABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DX_STACKSIZE=65536 -D_LARGEFILE                                     _SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=1 -DPLATFORM                                     ="cygwin" -D__POSIX__=1 -Wno-unused-parameter -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Idefault/deps                                     /c-ares -I../deps/c-ares ../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c -c -o default/deps/c-a                                     res/ares_strcasecmp_1.o
../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c:18:24: fatal error: ares_setup.h: No such file                                      or directory
 #include "ares_setup.h"
                        ^
compilation terminated.
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/user/node-v0.4.12/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cc ares_strcasecmp.c -> ares_strcasecmp_1.o}
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'program' failed
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build such an old version?

Comment: You can build a current version easily on Windows.

Comment: i prefer to use a linux-based os vs cmd.exe. that's why i'm using cygwin. versions of node that are newer than the one i'm using aren't supported on cygwin.

Comment: I don't know what you'd hope to accomplish with such an out of date and unsupported version of nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be extremely difficult to install node-v0.4.12 version with Cygwin on your Windows 7, as it's deprecated method.

If your requirements forbid you to install the latest Node on Windows using [simple installer](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22-x86.msi), and you have to use very old version you mentioned (node-v0.4.12), probably much easier solution would be to install that version on virtual machine with Linux.

Comment: thanks - i figured it'd be easier on an linux virtual machine. i'll go that route instead.